# Scala: Why can self-typed traits not see constructor args

Tags: scala, self-type

Why can I not see the constructor arg myval without defining it in the body of the class? Eg the trait is unable to see the constructor arg as shown here:

```
scala> class A(myval: String){}

scala> trait B {
     | this: A =>
     | println(myval)
     | }
<console>:8: error: not found: type A
       this: A =>
         ^
<console>:9: error: not found: value myval
       println(myval)
           ^
```

I'd have to declare the constructor arg again in the body of the class.

```
scala> class A(_myval: String){ val myval = _myval}
defined class A

scala> trait B {
     | this: A =>
     | println(myval)
     | }
defined trait B
```

Can someone help me understand why this is?

Answer (score 2):

It's because a `class` doesn't define a getter by default, so you have no access to `myval`.

If you do:

```
class A(_myval:String) {
  def myval = _myval
}

trait B {
  this : A => println(myval)
}
```

this works.

Your example would work "as is" with a `case class` as the getter would then automatically be built.

Edit: As per Rob Starling comment, you can shorten the class definition to `class A(val myval:String)`.

Comment: thanks - this is what I ended up doing for now. but any val I define in the body is available.

Comment: you can even do it more concisely by defining `A` as `class A(val myval: String);`

Comment: @JasonG yes because the default visibility in Scala is `public`. @Rob Nice tip didn't know that.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was thinking of trying to declare w/ val in the constructor. So it's a visibility thing then.